# Counter object in Python with public and private methods

Tags: python, object-oriented

I am trying to implement an open source desktop application with python. I want to provide both a gui and an API. I know there is no private methods in python but i am trying to find the most elegant way to keep some methods private. I do not want my users to see all list of methods while using API. After some research, I come up with the implementation below and wondering if there is any problem with my implementation of this concept and if there is any room for improvement. Please provide me a review and do not hesitate to ask any questions you have. Here is my try:

```
from pprint import pprint


# CamelCase because it "acts" like a class
def CounterController():
    class CounterControllerPrivate(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.counter = 0

        def add_one(self):
            self.counter += 1

        def reset(self):
            self.counter = 0

        def get_counter(self):
            return self.counter

    counter_controller = CounterControllerPrivate()

    class CounterControllerPublic(object):
        def add_one_endpoint(self):
            counter_controller.add_one()
            return counter_controller.get_counter()

        def reset_endpoint(self):
            counter_controller.reset()
            return counter_controller.get_counter()

    return CounterControllerPublic()


# counter attribute is not accessible from out here
controller = CounterController()

print(controller.add_one_endpoint())
print(controller.add_one_endpoint())
print(controller.reset_endpoint())

pprint(dir(controller))
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "cr105997.py", line 33, in <module>: controller.add_one_endpoint(): TypeError: add_one_endpoint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

Comment: you are right. it gets that error with python3 but works with python2. I didnt realized that. thank you. now checking and will be updating the code.

Comment: For the record, I got the same error with both Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: i figured that it was about static methods. changed it now. can you give it another chance?

Comment: What's the point of this code, if you cannot publicly query the counter value? If it's just a hypothetical example, then it's off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: Im sorry if it is wrong place to discuss. It is a code piece i wrote for my desktop application. Just name of the classes and methods are different to not show what i am trying to do. Point is: i am trying to hide some methods from users of the API i will provide with gui. I want to enforce them to use only specific methods and I am not experienced with python much, thats why wanted to discuss what is the best way to do that. Do you suggest me to ask this on software engineering stackexchange?

Comment: btw, this implementation brings the functionality i want but im not sure if it is best way to implement this.

Comment: I'd say that the question is too opinion-based for Software Engineering, but too hypothetical for Code Review. If you actually added a way to query the counter value, it could be considered working just well enough to qualify for a code review here, I think.

Comment: Okay, indeed these classes are more populated but i wanted to share here the minimum code possible. Let me add query methods too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The private objects and attributes are easily accessed using [`inspect.getclosurevars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars):

```
>>> c = CounterController()
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getclosurevars(c.add_one_endpoint)
ClosureVars(nonlocals={'counter_controller': <__main__.CounterController.<locals>.CounterControllerPrivate object at 0x10a047cf8>}, globals={}, builtins={}, unbound={'add_one'})
>>> _.nonlocals['counter_controller']
<__main__.CounterController.<locals>.CounterControllerPrivate object at 0x10a047cf8>
>>> _.counter
0
```

So you might consider whether it's worth spending a lot of effort on this approach. Personally I would spend the effort on API documentation instead.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about `inspect.getclosurecars`. It seems powerful. Is there any work around to disable this too?

Comment: The approach that I would recommend is to write documentation for the public methods and add a note that everything not documented is subject to change without notice in future versions. It's not worth your time fighting with users to control access to the code.

Comment: You are right. I will be accepting your answer and focusing on docs. However, I still love to have decorators for classes and methods to make them private for example. I understand it is conflicting the design motivations of the language but love to suggest and try to implement that. Any suggestions about where I can discuss this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Python classes operate under the principle of ["We are all consenting adults here"](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html).

This means that there is no real way to encapsulate your methods completely, there will always be a way to access them regardless (except if you make your code a thin wrapper on a C++ class with private members, or similar, and even that might not be foolproof).

The convention is for method names with one leading underscore to be considered internal methods, probably not for public consumption and method names with two leading underscores to be the closest thing to private you will get without a great effort. Python does some name mangling on the latter (by inserting the class name).

What this means is that these methods will still show up when calling `dir(obj)`, however, when working in an interactive session with tab completion, you need to explicitly start typing `obj._ObjectClass__m[Tab]` to access them, you will not get them with a simple `obj.m[Tab]`. It also means that when a subclass defines a method/attribute with the same name, there is no naming conflict with the base class.

In your documentation of the API you do not need to describe these methods at all, since it is the standard that they are not to be used. They should probably still have docstrings in the source code, though, if only for your own sake.

Some good further reading can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385317/private-variables-and-methods-in-python.

These conventions are also encoded in Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles):

> - `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an
>     underscore.
> - `single_trailing_underscore_`: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g. `Tkinter.Toplevel(master,
>     class_='ClassName')`
> - `__double_leading_underscore`: when naming a class attribute, invokes name mangling (inside class `FooBar`, `__boo` becomes
>     `_FooBar__boo`; see below).
> - `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`,
>     `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as
>     documented.

Comment: @GarethRees: You are right, I reworded that part. In any case it is described again in the part quoted from PEP8